Creating a button with an image in but the button hitbox is too large
I'm creating an app with custom tkinter and when I add the image and change the width and height of the button I get this horrible hitbox. How can I make it match the image?
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk

from customtkinter import CTkButton, CTkLabel, CTkEntry, CTkFrame, filedialog, CTk, CTkImage, CTkCanvas
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image


app = ctk.CTk()
app.geometry("350x800")
app.title("Students")

canvas = CTkCanvas(app, width=350, height=800, background="white")
canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

def sel_class_folder():
    class_folder = ctk.filedialog.askdirectory()

canvas.create_rectangle(201, 6, 321, 61, fill="white", outline="black")

folderSelectorUI = CTkImage(Image.open("./assets/classSelButton.png"), size=(165,38))
folderSelector = ctk.CTkButton(master=app, image=folderSelectorUI, text="", command=sel_class_folder, bg_color='white', width=50, height=38, fg_color="white", anchor="NW", corner_radius=0, hover_color="red", )
folderSelector.place(x=30, y=16)



app.mainloop()

Red = Button hitbox:


Make sure the image you're using for the button doesn't have a transparent border around it.

Does this help on line 21  size=(165,200))?
